# Model form labels translation

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, localization

I have included form labels in my translation as follows:

```
class GuestEmailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Guest
        fields = ['email']

        labels = {
            'email': _('Add your email for updates'),
        }
```

However, even though they show up in my translation files and I have added translations, they do not show up translated.

Is there a special way to handle labels in model forms?

Comment: What did you import as `_`? `gettext` or `gettext_lazy`?

Comment: I had imported as gettext but just switched over to gettext_lazy and seems to work. Thanks for the hint. Would you submit an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to work with `gettext_lazy` to postpone the translation process until the view is rendered.

You thus should import [**`gettext_lazy(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.gettext_lazy):

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
```